# Displaying the ASCII characters in C without unsigned char

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, infinite-loop

```
unsigned char a;

for(a=32;a<128;a=a+1)
printf("%d='%c'\t",a,a);
return(0);
```

Why do I have to put unsigned char? When I left it as char, I executed the program and it was giving me an infinite loop. Shouldn't it stop when a=127?

Comment: Why would it stop when `a` is 127?

Answer (score 3):

`char` means either it is `signed` or `unsigned` depends on implementation. This makes the behaviour of your code **implementation defined**.
It seems that on your machine it is `signed`. The minimum and maximum value of `signed char` is `-127` & `+127` respectively as per C standard. Any value greater that `127` or less than `-127` can't be assigned to `a` otherwise it will invoke **undefined behaviour**.

After `a` reaches `127`, it is incremented by one and the value becomes `128` which can't be hold by a `signed char` variable and hence the code invokes  undefined behaviour.

Comment: The specification is even (slightly) narrower: the range of `signed char` is defined to be `-127..127`. Any value outside it is "implementation defined". (That said, I've always happily used `-128` my entire life :)

Comment: @Jongware; You are right!! Never knew that before :)

Comment: @haccks: The C standard doesn't require the range of `signed char` to be -127 to 127. That's just the *minimum* range that the compiler is required to support. Most compilers use -128 to 127.

Comment: @Jongware: reason is that the standard does not enforce 2's complement, but leaves open for biased, sign-magnitude, 1's complement, etc. The latter two only range from -127, as they have two zeros (+/-).

Comment: @mastov; I removed the word *range*.

Comment: Yup to the above. I would call using `-128` *implementation defined*, rather than *undefined* behavior, because it's certainly not UB for Visual Studio.

Comment: @Jongware: An implementation is allowed to have a larger range, the standard only defines a minimal range. That's what `limits.h` is for. `char` can very well have 24 bits, for instance.

Comment: @haccks: But the sentence still means the same. You are talking about a *the* minimum value that *is* (precisely instead of "at most") -127. The compiler is well allowed to make guarantees for a larger range of values.

Answer (score 2):

On Visual Studio, the type `char` is the same as `signed char` and has a range of -128 to +127 (both included), so all values of `signed char` are below 128. Therefore the loop condition `a < 128` is always fulfilled and the loop never stops.

When you have `unsigned char`, the value of `a` reaches 128 at some point and there won't be a next iteration. In change, if you try to increase a `signed char` variable of value 127 (expecting it to take the value 128), the result is undefined. On most platforms (including Visual Studio) it will wrap around (overflow because 127 is the highest possible value) to the lowest possible value -128.

Comment: Answer is wrong. There is no wrap around in case of `signed char`. `signed` overflow invokes UB.

Comment: @haccks: On most platforms it does wrap around, although technically you are right in that you can't rely on that.

Comment: Also, the range need not be `-128` to `127`.

Comment: Whoo, if we start taking into account everything that is not properly defined in C, this will be a loooong and poorly focused answer. But yes, I try to work that in, too. Btw. the question is tagged "Visual Studio" and there things *are* defined the way I explained it (both for the overflow and the range).

Comment: @haccks: Wrap-around is one possible outcome of UB.   Therefore you cannot say it is "wrong".   It also happens to be the outcome of most compilers.

Comment: Relevant link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx, "range .. –128 to 127 by default", which is allowed by the official C specification. It *is* implementation defined but, well, the OP mentions a specific implementation and so it should not be a problem. (Except when he assumes the same code will work on any other system and/or compiler.)

Answer (score 1):

Whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation dependent and may change by compiler and target architecture.

For most (likely all modern) CPU architectures, `signed char` has a range of -128...127, `unsigned char` has 0...255 (see your `limits.h`, the minimum range is -127...127, no upper limit).

So, `char` appears to be signed for your example. As compares are done using `int` here (type coercion - implicit conversion), the condition of your loop will always be true, thus the loop never terminates.

Using unsigned benefits from the extended range, so the loop operates normally.

Note that if doing arithmetic on `char`, always use explicitly `signed` or `unsigned`. The latter is often the better choice. If you enable warnings, the compiler might help you with that. However, do not rely on this (but follow the warnings showing up).